Add another regex statement for updating copyright year in emacs
I have the following copyright information that needs to be updated with current year...
# Copyright (C) A Company, Inc. :y, all rights reserved.

I want to replace :y with the current year. I'm trying to add the test for :y to the copyright-regexp variable but haven't been able to figure it out.
I was hoping to just add |:y to the end of the regex, but it doesn't work & actually breaks the year replacement...
\(©\|@copyright{}\|[Cc]opyright\s *:?\s *\(?:(C)\)?\|[Cc]opyright\s *:?\s *©\)\s *\(?:[^0-9\n]*\s *\)?\([1-9]\([-0-9, ';/*%#\n\t]\|\s<\|\s>\)*[0-9]+\|:y\)

The above is from customize-variable on copyright-regexp
Also for the final solution, can you provide the string that I would actually use in the EL file? with the additional escape characters. I would assume the above would look like in the lisp file...
"\\(©\\|@copyright{}\\|[Cc]opyright\\s *:?\\s *\\(?:(C)\\)?\
\\|[Cc]opyright\\s *:?\\s *©\\)\
\\s *\\(?:[^0-9\n]*\\s *\\)?\
\\([1-9]\\([-0-9, ';/*%#\n\t]\\|\\s<\\|\\s>\\)*[0-9]+\\|:y\\)"

Thanks
I tried
\(©\|@copyright{}\|[Cc]opyright\s *:?\s *\(?:(C)\)?\|[Cc]opyright\s *:?\s *©\)\s *\(?:[^0-9\n]*\s *\)?\([1-9]\([-0-9, ';/*%#\n\t]\|\s<\|\s>\)*[0-9]+\|:y\)


You shouldn't use |. That's for making an alternative. But this isn't an alternative to words like Copyright, it's after that. So it shoiuld be something like \(all the alternatives\) *:y

Then it gets replaced with \\1 2024
